# How to position the Dropdown Panel just below the textbox of mat-select

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular Material 14.0.4` and `Angular 15.1.3`.

I have a `mat-select` dropdown which is written this way...

```
<mat-select value="5" panelClass="custom-panel">
    <mat-option value="5">5</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="10">10</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="20">20</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In this I have applied `panelClass` with its code in css as below...

```
.custom-panel {
    top: calc(100% + 10px) !important;
}
```

And it is still coming as below. Overlapping of the dropdown list with its textbox

This is the dropdown when it is not selected

[image: Show Dropdown]

This is the dropdown when it is selected

[image: Selected Dropdown]

How to place the panel just below the textbox on selection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below css to do that!

We use the css `transform` to move the panel to the bottom!

```
.custom-panel {
  transform: translateY(25px) !important;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kqys5e?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.scss&title=node.new%20Starter)

Comment: Stackblitz is not loading the preview panel. Just stopped there..

Comment: @CPK_2011 you need to run `cd test` then `npm run start` to see the output

Comment: Still it is not working for me.. Should I need to update any material related css or theme files?

Comment: @CPK_2011 We need to do `cd test` then `npm install` then `npm run start` my mistake!

Comment: Your Stackblitz code is working now. But in my local it is not working..

Comment: @CPK_2011 We need to include this CSS in the global css file! `styles.scss` or `styles.css`, inspect element the dropdown and check why its not applying, then plz ping me the details!