# How to position Dropdown Panel when the panel goes up in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am following the below question to display Dropdown little downwards..

[Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77798326/how-to-position-the-dropdown-panel-just-below-the-textbox-of-mat-select)

How to check if the Dropdown Panel goes up like below...

[image: Upwards]

Comment: It can either goes up or down based on the screen size. How to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have requirement like that, just go for margin set at the top and the bottom, this will ensure whether it opens up or down, it will get offset by a specified amount!

[css margin docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

```
// apply space based on class
.custom-panel {
  margin: 25px 0px;
}
.custom-panel-2 {
  margin: 30px 0px;
}

// apply globally for all select
.mat-select-panel {
  margin: 25px 0px;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nfva5g?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.scss&title=node.new%20Starter)

Comment: Is there anything like automatically displaying the panel based on the textbox size? With single fix, I can apply for all that kind of dropdowns with single css change?

Comment: @CPK_2011 Do you want to apply this fix globally?

Comment: @CPK_2011 I dont understand what you mean by "Is there anything like automatically displaying the panel based on the textbox size"

Comment: Yes. I want to fix it globally in a certian project. Sometimes, the textbox height may be 30px and some other textbox height  may be 35px. So based on its size, I would like to display the panel either top or bottom accordingly.

Comment: @CPK_2011 There is no relationship between the dropdown tag and the dropdown that opens, they are separated from each other, you need to add a different CSS class for both of them like `.custom-panel` and `.custom-panel-2` and set the heights differently, I also shared the CSS to globally apply for all dropdowns!