# How to align the width of the Dropdown Panel to its Textbox in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am following this Answer for the Dropdown panel to display just below or above the Dropdown Textbox

[Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77824054/how-to-position-dropdown-panel-when-the-panel-goes-up-in-angular)

Now I am having the same Dropdown panel like this..

```
<mat-select disableOptionCentering (selectionChange)="validateInputs(userForm)" formControlName="siteId" placeholder="Select Site ID"       panelClass="custom-panel-siteId">
     <input 
     (keyup)="onFilterOptions($event.target.value)" 
     matInput
     class="filter-select-options"
     autocomplete="off"
     type="text"
     placeholder="Search Site ID">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
    {{option}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

But the panel is extending outside of the textbox as below...

[image: Dropdown Width]

As highlighted in yellow color, the width of the panel is increasing little bit..

Also, I am using below code in `styles.scss` file..But is is not aligning properly..

```
.custom-panel-siteId {
  margin: 45px 0px !important;
}
```

**EDIT**

The style details are as below when I do an Inspect Element in Developer Tools

[image: mat-select-panel]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Styles]

**SECOND EDIT**

Now with the latest code changes, the panel is coming as per the width of the Dropdown Textbox. But it is moving little left side as below...

[image: Moving Left]

Comment: just do an inspect element and check the dropdown like last time, you will find out the problematic CSS, also check if the mat select is full width or if you added padding to it!

Comment: Now the alignments are working fine. It is placing the panel just below the Dropdown Textbox. Only the width is not decreasing..Modifying the Question also..

Comment: In the third box of the last screenshot in the Question, it is trying to set the `max-width` to `280px`. So, the width is not increasing.. How to override that?

Comment: In the first box of the last screenshot in the Question, it is trying to set the `min-width` to `calc(100% + 32px)`. If I remove that `32px` in that, then the panel fits correctly to the `Dropdown Textbox`. I searched for `calc(100% + 32px)` in the whole project. But I could not find it anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the width using the same CSS block. Please apply the below change! As per your analysis, we need to override `min-width: calc(100% + 32px)` so we can add the `min-width` and force (`!important`) set it to `100%`.

```
.custom-panel.override-1.override-2.override-3 {
  margin: 25px 0px;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

html

```
<mat-select 
panelClass="custom-panel override-1 override-2 override-3">
...
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-o4jvps)

Comment: Still it is not working.. The other code of `min-width` is overriding...

Comment: I used like this also... `::ng-deep {
  .mat-select-panel, .custom-panel-siteId {
    margin: 44px 0px !important;
    min-width: 100% !important;
  }
}` But still it is not working..

Comment: @CPK_2011 add multiple classes and increase the specificity of the CSS class, this will ensure it gets overridden, if you hover over the class in the right side panel of inspect element, you can see the specificity

Comment: Please provide an example on how it should be implemented.

Comment: Using multiple classes is also not working...

Comment: @CPK_2011 add these to the `styles.scss` global style file, instead of ng-deep

Comment: Added and the width is decreased. But it is moving little left side. Updated the question. Please check..

Comment: @CPK_2011 try `margin-left: 15px` just play around the CSS, until you find the right fit!